# Copy from MySQL Workbench to Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, mysql-workbench

I have to build reports, and I need to do some database queries, which return a bunch of results.

Is there a way I can copy 1+ rows/columns and copy them into an excel sheet? the excel sheet is formatted a particular way, and the data needs to be placed in there a certain way, so how can I copy and paste from mysql workbench into excel?

Comment: Select what you would like to copy in MySQL Workbench and right-click and select "Copy Field Content (unquoted)" go to Excel and do "Paste Values".

Comment: I think that just copies one field and not one column and/or row

Comment: No you can select a range of data.  Just like selecting a range of data in Excel.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  You can just select a range and do a CTRL + C to copy.  Then go to Excel and do the paste.

Comment: Running into a similar issue. I can only select a single line of a query result on MySQL workbench (in Ubuntu), making it impossible to copy paste multiple result rows without exporting the data into a csv. If you know any workaround...

Comment: You can copy all rows of the result set from MySQL Workbench clicking on the upper left corner of the grid to select all rows and columns, then you move the mouse pointer to any row, right click and choose "Copy Row (tab separated)", and finally paste to Excel. Unfortunately header row is not copied to Excel, and I don't know an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I could come up with is to use a different program:

http://www.heidisql.com/

So far this program works great! I like it a lot better than MySQL Workbench as well!

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. The requirement is to do this task using MySQL Workbench

Comment: It's good but crashes a lot !! that is very annoying :-/ Going back to MSWB :S

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to workbench and select the rows that you need. Copy them.
2. On your pc create a new file, paste the data in it. Save it as .csv
3. Open the newly created csv file in MS Excel. The data will be nicely formatted.

Answer (score 0):

it might be a little late but there is a button to Export/import so you can save it as .csv, also dont forget to set 'Don't Limit' on query result

[image: tableExportButton]

Answer (score -1):

In my requirement I have to copy the column name, data type and its constraint. 
I executed command

```
desc tableName
```

Where tableName is required table name.
in heidisql to execute query you have to press "F9" key.
It will display the whole structure of table. Now to copy paste in excel you have to right click on result then you can see

[image]

"export grid rows"

third last option in right click.
then select radio button File then select file name. 
No need of any alteration in encoding part and you can select from output format e.g. excel csv, html table etc.
and then ok.
Go and open your file then complete result will be copied to the excel sheet.
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. The requirement is to do this task using MySQL Workbench